# Any risk of hosting a public website on my home network? Year 2015

Tags: windows-8.1, security, iis, asp.net, web-hosting

I have read the following post but it was already 6 years ago so I'm wondering if anything has changed over the last few years in terms of security because I heard windows firewall has been improved alot:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624815/risks-of-hosting-public-web-site-right-on-my-network

I have created my first website using ASP.NET and SQL Server and successfully hosted on IIS (on port 80). In order to make it so that the website is visible to everyone in the world, I logged-in to my router and portforwarded port 80 to my home pc ip address and set the windows 8 firewall inbound setting to open up port 80. Now, whenever I visit my public ip address, my website loads successfully. Everytime I block port 80 from my windows firewall, visits to my website is blocked as intended. Since only port 80 is opened and the port is setup specifically for my website hosted on IIS, would there be any security risks of getting hacked? I'm using the computer as my personal computer as well. And there are 3 more computers that are connected to my router wirelessly. Would hosting a website on my home computer make the other computers and my home computer be more vulnerable to hacks? Would buying a new computer exclusively for hosting website help reduce the risks?

I have considered doing the following methods setting up DMZ and Intranet routers: http://dfarq.homeip.net/2011/11/how-to-make-a-dmz-with-two-routers/ http://www.pcwintech.com/how-setup-two-or-more-routers-together-port-forwarding-port-triggering

but I cannot make it work. Even if this method works, would it be necessary for today's standard?

Comment: Other people will be able to give you a lot of advise however first thing that springs to my mind quickly is the risk of something like a malware injection infecting your IIS machine and potentially all machines on the network. This is where having a DMZ helps because it is not part of your main network. If the DMZ is proving hard to setup think about setting up another VLAN on your router with two separate IP ranges so that the machine hosting IIS is separate from your home network this will kind of achieve similar benefits..

Comment: Being Apache Web Server is more reliable and secure, you could run asp.net site in Apache. As most of the people will prefer Apache in a Linux environment rather than IIS in Windows. Apache is also available for Windows in WAMP or XAMPP package http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-asp-pages-apache-server-49752.html